# Failed to parse configuration class, when starting Spring Boot application as Docker image

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, gradle

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app/logs/
COPY ./storefront/build/libs/storefront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "storefront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

start.sh

```
sudo docker build ./ -t platform
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 platform
```

Error:

```
2020-05-11 11:53:01.925 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [lv.dz.platform.storefront.StorefrontApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/daniel/projects/MY/platform/storefront/src/main/resources/application.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Note:

Working with `java -jar storefront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `./gradlew bootRun`

Any ideas?

**Update:**

Issue was in one of the modules (not storefront), where @PropertySource was defined as full path to application.properties. Resolved by removing this line, since it was old code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its works in you computer, because you have dependency to your local file `/home/daniel/projects/MY/platform/storefront/src/main/resources/application.properties`. After building and running java file inside container your code still tries fo load `application.properties` file from `/home/daniel/projects/MY/platform/storefront/src/main/resources/application.properties` which is not exists inside container.

Inside you application change absolute path to relative.
Use dockers feature [multi-staged build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). Build your jar file during building an docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to to put property out of jar like below ?

`ADD application.properties /usr/app/application.properties
ENTRYPOINT ["java" ,"--spring.config.location=classpath:file:/usr/app/application.properties","-jar","storefront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]`